# Views show weird SQL query

Tags: views

I am using Views to display some comment for specify node.

The SQL query on Views pane:

```
SELECT comment.uid AS comment_uid, comment.cid AS cid, comment.created AS comment_created, 'comment' AS field_data_comment_body_comment_entity_type
FROM 
{comment} comment
INNER JOIN {node} node_comment ON comment.nid = node_comment.nid
WHERE (( (node_comment.nid = '1330' ) )AND(( (comment.status <> '0') AND (node_comment.status = '1') )))
ORDER BY comment_created DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

I try to copy above sql to phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT comment.uid AS comment_uid, comment.cid AS cid, comment.created AS comment_created, 'comment' AS field_data_comment_body_comment_entity_type
FROM 
comment
INNER JOIN node_comment ON comment.nid = node_comment.nid
WHERE (( (node_comment.nid = '1330' ) )AND(( (comment.status <> '0') AND (node_comment.status = '1') )))
ORDER BY comment_created DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

But phpmyadmin throw an error to me:

```
Error Code: 1146. Table 'daxuebao.node_comment' doesn't exist
```

I try to search `drupal node_comment table` at google, But I get nothing.

Comment: Your query is wrong.. Just remove braces {} from Views Query and execute..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no table named `node_comment`. You must do the `inner join` to the `node` table, in the same way as the Views query.

```
SELECT comment.uid AS comment_uid, comment.cid AS cid, comment.created AS comment_created, 'comment' AS field_data_comment_body_comment_entity_type
FROM 
comment
INNER JOIN node node_comment ON comment.nid = node_comment.nid
WHERE (( (node_comment.nid = '1330' ) )AND(( (comment.status <> '0') AND (node_comment.status = '1') )))
ORDER BY comment_created DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```